# phonegap google play and mail link

Tags: android, cordova, email

I've a problem with links.

I want to add an android / ios market link. and mail link and image from external url.

**tried for market link;**

```
1. <a href="market://details?=com.my.app">App</a>
2. <a href="market://details?=com.my.app" data-rel="external">App</a>
3. <a href="https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.my.app" data-rel="external">App</a>
```

**tried for mail link;**

```
<a href="mailto:my@my.com" data-rel="external">my@my.com</a>
```

and config.xml file;

```
<access origin="mailto://my@my.com" launch-external="yes" />
```

**image from external URL;**

```
<img src="http://a.my.com/img.png" />
```

config.xml file;

```
<access origin="http://*.my.com" />
```

but not working. How can I add links? Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

install [inappbrowser](http://plugins.cordova.io/#/package/org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser) plugin
install [email composer](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-email-composer)

To open Temple Run in play store

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function openTR(){
            window.open("market://details?id=com.imangi.templerun2", "_system");
        }
        function sendEmail(){
            cordova.plugins.email.open({
            app: 'gmail',
            to:      'my@my.com',
            subject: 'Greetings',
            body:    'How are you?'
            });
        }
        function openLink(link){
            window.open(link, '_blank', 'location=yes');
        }
</script>

<input type="button" value="Temple Run" onclick="openTR()">
<input type="button" value="Send Email" onclick="sendEmail()">
```

**EDIT** check `openLink` function defenition above
while creating `<li>` elements using js

```
"<li onclick='openLink(\"+"value.link+"\")' />"+value.title+"</li>"
```

**[Output](http://tinypic.com/r/b5h177/8)**

Comment: requires 15 reputation :(

Comment: reading links from json file. how can write this link correctly. output += '<li><a href="#" onclick="window.open("'+ value.link +'", "_system");">' + value.title + '</a></li>';

Comment: have you added `openLink(link)` definition. Post your `JS` code so that I could help.. New question is preferable.

Comment: new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29569639/writing-link-value-from-json-file

Answer (score 0):

I usually do something like this:

1. In string file

   ```
   <string name="my_link"><a ref="https://google.com">Click This Link!</a></string>
   ```
2. in layout

   ```
   <TextView
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:clickable="true"
       android:text="@string/my_link"
       android:autoLink="web" />
   ```

Answer (score 0):

From Javascript,

```
window.location.href = "mailto:support@google.com";
window.location.href = "market://details?=com.my.app";
```

This will do the wonder.