# writing link value from json file

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

building an app with phonegap for android and reading content from local json file.

but i can't add link my output. it works without link, but when i try to add link value, it doesn't work.

works with this codes.

```
$(document).on("pagebeforeshow", "#page", function(){ 
$.getJSON("res/veri/content.json", function(data){
    console.log(data);
    var output = '';
    $.each(data, function (index, value) {
        output += "<li>"+value.title+"</li>";                               
    });
    $('#list').html(output).listview("refresh");
});
});
```

but i want add to link value;

first of all added

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function openLink(link){
        window.open(link, '_blank', 'location=yes');
    }
</script>
```

and changed;

```
"<li onclick='openLink(\"+"value.link+"\")' />"+value.title+"</li>";
```

but, it doesn't works.. how can fix the error. thanks.

Comment: Are you able to create List Items Can you provide your sample json object, i mean value of `console.log(data);`

Comment: my json file example: http://www.codeshare.io/IzuhJ yes, without link value it works.

Comment: Can you give screen shot with and without link value

Comment: without link: https://yadi.sk/i/lM6bYLAJfudfy with link: doesn't open this page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
'<li><a href="' + value.link + '" data-rel="external">' + value.title + '</a></li>';
```

it work with this code.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this work...

```
var link = $("<a href='" + value.link + "'></a>");
link.get(0).click();
```

Maybe you can do some variation on it with something you've already got.

```
"<li onclick='link.get(0).click();' />"+value.title+"</li>";
```

Just an idea.

Comment: Set a variable called "link" to a href tag with url you want to go to.

Answer (score 0):

[demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZYdroa)[image]

```
$(document).on("pagebeforeshow", "#page", function(){ 
  $.getJSON("res/veri/content.json", function(data){
    console.log(data);
    $.each(data, function (index, value) {
      $('#list').append('<li class="listElement" onclick="openLink('+value.link+')">'+value.title+'</li>'
      );
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: but nothing happens when I click. added <access origin="*" /> to config.xml